# Pass Angular object property through variable?

Tags: angularjs

Controller:

```
$scope.item = {"name": "b", "code": 3}
$scope.foo = "name";
```

How to access {{item.name}} through 'foo'?

This doesn't work:

HTML:

```
{{item.{{foo}}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this template HTML:

```
{{item[foo]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use square brackets to access the value of variable as a key of object. You are nesting the angular expression `{{}}` within another which is incorrect to access the value of key of the object.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.item = {"name": "b", "code": 3}
   $scope.foo = "name";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

  <p>{{item[foo]}}</p>

</div>
```

Comment: He doesn't need item.foo, but item[foo] which is evaluated to item["name"].

Comment: @plvice oh yes. My bad